# How to Display data in textbox using MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, textbox, oledbdataadapter, oledbdatareader

Im trying to display user data from database into textbox, so that user can edit/update that data later.

Im getting error of **no value has been set for at least one of the required parameters.**

I did not write the SELECT * FROM, because i'm not displaying data like AdminRights.

Can you please help me fix the error?

This is my code

```
private void refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Name], [LastName], [UserName], [Password], [Address], [Email] FROM User WHERE [ID] = ?", con);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                name.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
                lName.Text = (dr["LastName"].ToString());
                uName.Text = (dr["UserName"].ToString());
                pass.Text = (dr["Password"].ToString());
                address.Text = (dr["Address"].ToString());  
                email.Text = (dr["Email"].ToString());
                id.Text = (dr["ID"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question mark should be replaced by an actual ID.

Comment: @Abbas, The app has many users. If i select one specific ID, it will always show the data of the same user.

Comment: then you should get all data from the db and run a foreach!

Comment: @Sajeetharan can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
.....FROM User WHERE [ID] = ?", con);
```

The ? placeholder requires a parameter defined in the command parameters collection.

So, before calling ExecuteReader you need to add the parameter for the ID field

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ????value for the ID field);
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

If you want to retrieve a single record from your table you need to know the value for the field that uniquely identifies the records in your table.
To get that value it is necessary to understand how do you reach this code. If you select a row from a list, grid or combo, probably you have loaded that control with your user names and their ID.

Comment: But how can i set one specific parameter, where the database has many users with different ID's?

Comment: It is necessary to understand how do you reach this code. Do you select the user name from a listbox, grid or something like those control?

Comment: I use a button named "Refresh". And when i click it, the data is supposed to display in the TextBoxes

Comment: Is there a user that is logged in to the application? If so, get the ID of that user and use that ID to get a single record from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String id = idTextBox.Text;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select *from User Where [ID]= "+ id +" ");
        command.Connection = conn;
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        conn.Open();
        dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            name.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
            lName.Text = (dr["LastName"].ToString());
            uName.Text = (dr["UserName"].ToString());
            pass.Text = (dr["Password"].ToString());
            address.Text = (dr["Address"].ToString());  
            email.Text = (dr["Email"].ToString());
            id.Text = (dr["ID"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
```

this will work fine change lines and execute